# regarding the phrase "carry perspective" and "carry standpoint"

Tags: meaning, phrases, finance

I've encountered a phrase that I can't make out as yet despite my futile attempts to look it up in several dictionaries, along with browsing several online articles containing such phrase. 
It's in a financial related text (so it isn't about gun's shooting distance) and it appears to mean "in the long run," "from a long-term perspective," along these lines. 
I'll post some contexts below where the phrase is used in a similar:

(a)Because the de-coupling between cable and EUR/USD does not seem to have been triggered by clear economic event, its hard to say for how long this will continue. However, for the time being, if you want to be long USD this may be best expressed through EUR/USD, but if you want to be short USD, then it looks like cable is providing the extra extra zing (and its more attractive from a carry perspective).

(b)From a carry perspective, we expect AUD’s 2.5% interest rate advantage over the JPY to be maintained for the medium term, which could make AUDJPY an attractive prospect, especially if overall market sentiment remains stable for the next few weeks in the wake of the resolution of the US fiscal crisis.

(c) Asian credit increasingly attractive from a carry perspective (headline)...But spreads over Treasuries remain wide. The current spread is 277.8 basis points (bp), which is around the same level as in late 2009. Five-year treasuries are yielding 0.63%. As such, despite historically low yields in Asian credit, from a carry perspective it remains very attractive..."So the more you think that sub-par economic growth or central bankers choosing to maintain rates low will continue for an unusual amount of time, the more appealing Asian credit will look from a pure carry perspective,"...

It seems to have a positive connotation since in the examples above including the text where I read it in the first place, usually with the adjective "attractive" near it, e.g. Despite...it looks attractive from a carry perspective.
I suspect "from a carry standpoint" shares a similar meaning with this phrase, if not synonymous.

I look forward to hearing from you all. Thank you.

Best,

Alvis

Comment: Thank you for your warm welcome and advice. I actually have. But I think the collocation (carry+perspective) carries a particular meaning that belongs to the market analysts'/bankers' lingo. I've already tried my SOD, Merriam-Webster's Unabridged Dictionary and its collegiate 11 edition, Random House Webster's Unabridged Dictionary, along with other learner's dictionaries, of no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the meaning of *carry* derives from metaphorically *carrying X on the books* (that is to say, in good old-fashioned pen-and-ink bookkeeping, the entry would be carried over from one period to another). That usage is probably more familiar as part of the phrase *to carry over*.

The *perspective* and *standpoint* are just an altogether too common and quite awkward turn of phrase common in the business world. (I'm almost surprised that you didn't also find *carry-wise*.) Both essentially mean *when considered as an item to be carried* or *when considered as a medium-to-long-term holding*.